# Inverse of array_intersect()

Tags: php, arrays

Arguments are like this:

```
function foo(arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4 ...)
```

and the function should return a array of all elements from arr2, arr3, arr4 ... that don't exist in arr1.

Is there a built in function for this? Or do I need to make it myself with foreach and stuff? :)

Comment: In set theory it would be called the complement

Comment: dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582242/opposite-of-array-intersect

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no built-in function that does exactly what you are asking for.  `array_diff()` is close, but not quite.  So you'll have to roll your own nice neat function or else do something ugly like this:

```
array_diff( array_unique(
                array_merge(
                    array_values($arr2), 
                    array_values($arr3), 
                    array_values($arr4)
                )),
                $arr1 
           );
```

You can remove the call to `array_unique()` if you want values that appear multiple times in the arrays to also be represented multiple times in your result.

You can remove the calls to `array_values()` if your keys in your arrays are all numeric or if you are certain that there are no non-numeric keys that appear in more than one of the arrays being merged.

So, in those ideal circumstances, it can be simplified to:

```
array_diff( array_merge( $arr2, $arr3, $arr4 ), $arr1 );
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with array_diff, but you'll have to turn things around a bit.

```
$result = array_diff (array_merge ($arr2, $arr3, $arr4), $arr1);
```

**EDIT**: Trott's answer covers a load of edge cases that mine doesn't. That's probably the best solution you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

That is what you're looking for :

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php